# Como consumir un Web Service desde Java de forma dinámica

Tags: java, webservice, netbeans-8.2

en Java NetBeans puedo consumir un Web Service de php agregandolo mediante RPC, se me crean varios archivos con todos los metodos que contiene el Web Service.
Pero me di cuenta que funciona de manera estática, es decir, que funciona solo con la URL que se le ingresó en un principio, si el Web Service cambia de servidor habría que volver a importarlo desde la nueva URL en la aplicación Java para poder consumirlo.
De que manera se puede realizar de forma dinámica, que al inicio de secion se ingrese la URL y mediante ella se conecte al Web Service sin problemas

Hasta ahora estos son los metodos de consumir el WS

```
META.Service _service = new META.Service_Impl();
META.ServicePortType _port = _service.getServicePort();
META.Registro[] reg = _port.getUltimosRegistros();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No he consumido servicio de php pero si de otros ws, y en todos se pueden sobreescribir la url del ws, solo revisa la clase META.Service  si tiene algun metodo al que le puedas pasar la URL, ejemplo puede ser _service.setEndpoint("AQUI_LA_URL"), y pues el valor del URL, lo parametrizas.

Comment: Gracias, en RPC está en la clase "PortType_Stub" alli se encuentra la url y los métodos los cuales hay que parametrizar.